# O que são URl "BLOB"

Tags: html

Estou encontrando com certa frequência (ALTA) "URL's" normalmente de videos que começam com "blob:" e a "URL" normalmente, porém, ao tentar carregar esse link eu me deparo com o erro dessa URL não ser valida.
Levando como exemplo a TAG e seu SRC abaixo:

```html
<video preload="" src="blob:https://player.vimeo.com/0910c487-95db-474b-a452-909659339de3"></video>
```

Estou ficando bem frustado com esse novo sistema de URL.

Comment: Pergunta no nosso site irmão: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30864573/1452488

Comment: Traduzi um pequeno trecho de uma resposta [neste link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16179887/1377664) mas dá pra ter uma certa noção do que se trata: "_Uma URL `blob:` não se refere a informações existentes no servidor, se refere a informações que o navegador tem atualmente na memória, para a página atual. Elas não estarão disponíveis: em outras páginas, em outros navegadores e em outros computadores._"

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Traduzido do Stack Overflow em Inglês. Confira a original [neste link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30881444/916193).</sub>

---

URLs de blob (da [W3C](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#DefinitionOfScheme), nome oficial) ou URLs de objeto (da [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Parameters), nome do método) são usados ​​com um objeto [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) ou [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).

Os URLs de blob só podem ser gerados internamente pelo navegador. [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) criará uma referência especial para o objeto Blob ou File que mais tarde pode ser liberada usando `URL.revokeObjectURL()`][6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL). Esses URLs só podem ser usados ​​localmente em uma única instância do navegador e na mesma sessão (ou seja, durante a vida útil da página/documento).

É um "pseudoprotocolo", e existe para permitir que objetos Blob e File sejam usados ​​como fonte de URL para coisas como imagens, links de download para dados binários e assim por diante, que não tem como ser linkados de outra forma por não se tratarem de um recurso externo de fato.

Por exemplo, você não pode entregar um pacote bruto de objeto Imagem, pois o navegador não sabe a intenção do seu uso. Imagens (que são dados binários) são normalmente carregadas por meio de URLs. Isso se aplica a qualquer coisa que exija um URL como fonte.  Assim, em vez de fazer o upload dos dados binários e servi-los de volta por meio de um URL, é melhor usar uma etapa local extra para poder acessar os dados diretamente sem passar por um servidor.

Também é uma alternativa melhor para Data-URI que são strings codificadas como [Base-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). O problema com Data-URI é que cada caractere consome mais espaço em JavaScript. Além disso, 33% é adicionado ao tamanho dos dados devido à codificação Base-64. Os Blobs, por sua vez, são arrays de bytes binários puros que não têm nenhuma sobrecarga significativa como Data-URI, o que os torna mais rápidos e menores de manusear.

Vale notar que URLs de Blob/URLs de Objetos só podem ser criados internamente no navegador. Você pode fazer Blobs e obter o objeto File por meio da API File Reader, embora BLOB signifique apenas Binary Large OBject e seja armazenado como matrizes de bytes. Um cliente pode solicitar que os dados sejam enviados como ArrayBuffer ou como um Blob. O servidor deve enviar os dados como dados binários puros. Bancos de dados geralmente usam Blob para descrever objetos binários também e, em essência, estamos falando basicamente de matrizes de bytes.

Para usar o recurso você precisa encapsular os dados binários como um objeto BLOB e usar `URL.createObjectURL()` para gerar uma URL local para ele:

```js
var blob = new Blob([arrayBufferWithPNG], {type: "image/png"}),
    url = URL.createObjectURL(blob),
    img = neu Image();

img.onload = function() {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src); //limpa a memoria
    document.body.appendChild(this); // adiciona imagem ao DOM
}

img.src = url; // agora pode "transmitir" os bytes
```

Observe que `URL` pode precisar ser prefixado em navegadores webkit, então use isto para compatibilidade com implementações mais antigas:

```js
var url = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(...);
```